# Extracting just date from column in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with different types of notes: TBD, September, 9/25/2022, 9/25, etc.

I want to pull out in column B just the dates, and then in column C show the day of the week.  Right now if the field in column B is blank, Column C defaults to Saturday with the formula =text(B2,"dddd")

Because of the variation of text in column A, I haven't been able to figure out which type of formula will work to just pull out the date and then leave blank if its not a date

[Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-U7QLdHlPTq1UWHrtKEBmjLh36cIzbip_FNco87sIq4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What have you tried.  Try doing this yourself and come back if you run into problems

Comment: If you all you need are just the dates, check if the cell is a number (under the hood, dates are numbers), then get the value if its a number

Comment: try `=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,)`. This should work for cells that contain only dates

Comment: @MWaheed that was it.  I don't know how in all my variations of searches ISNUMBER as a formula didn't come up!

Answer (score 1):

**Paste this formula in `B1`**

```
=ArrayFormula({"Date","Day of week";
 TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A),A2:A,""),"dd/mm/yyyy"),
 text(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A),A2:A,""),"dddd")
 })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below formulas

```
D2=INDEX(TEXT(A2:A,"mm/dd/e;;;"))
E2=INDEX(TEXT(A2:A,"dddd;;;"))
```

See you sheet `D2` and `E2` cell.